# Cite with multibib

Tags: citing, multibib

I'm using `multibib` and want to cite everything as *(author, year)*.

When I'm using `\citet` with the original bibtex, I get the right style,
but when I'm using it with the second bibliography, I get *author (year)*

In my preamble I have defined `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` and `\newcites{web}{Webpages}`
In my bibliographies im using `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` and `\bibliographystyleweb{agsm}`.

Comment: Two observations. (i) Since you're using the `agsm` bibliography style, which is part of the `harvard` package, you should load the `har2nat` package in addition to `natbib`. (ii) Use `\citep` (instead of `\cite` or `\citet`) if you want to be sure to get parenthesis-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Any updates? If you need still help please a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)